# Mixed-integer quadratic programming, state of art

Tags: quadratic-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I used Gurobi with a MIQP with 26 binary variables and 26*4 interaction term without any other constraint. The speed is very slow already.... I want to ask what is the state of art of MIQP solvers. Generally how many variable can it handle or do we need to manually input linearization techniques to enhance the speed. thank you:)

Comment: Number of variables is not a very useful indication of how hard your model is to solve.  Please tell us what your model is instead.

Comment: As it stands, your question is a bit too broad in scope.  Selection of the appropriate solver highly depends on the properties of the problem and cannot be generalized.  Until more details about the specific problem are provided, this question will be on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For LPs, MILPs, and QPs, Gurobi and CPLEX are considered best-of-breed. They beat any open-source general-purpose solver by at least an order of magnitude. I see no reason why that would be different for QPs. Both companies have dedicated teams that comb the literature for various cuts to use in constructing a branch-and-bound tree, and employ heuristics that perform well in terms of trying out these various cuts at different points in the algorithm. Both solvers also have sophisticated presolve routines that preprocess the input optimization problem to speed up the solver algorithms employed after preprocessing, and these routines often make a big difference in solution time compared to an equivalent solver that does not use those presolve routines.

One way you can "beat CPLEX and Gurobi" is to exploit structure, which has been done successfully in stochastic programming. For your problem, without more information, it is difficult to say whether you can exploit structure to accelerate time to solution. Formulation is important for MILPs and MINLPs, so I wouldn't be surprised if it is also important for MIQPs. You might also try alternate formulations of your problem to see if you can achieve better results, or try looking at the verbose output of Gurobi's solver and see if you can change solver input parameters to speed up time to solution.

I'd also say that number of variables is a very coarse indicator of problem difficulty. What matters more is how much of the branch-and-bound tree needs to be explored. There are large problem instances out there that do not require much of the branch-and-bound tree to be enumerated. I don't work with MIQPs much, but for MILPs, I've successfully solved problem instances with several thousand integer variables because only a small portion of the branch-and-bound tree must be enumerated. Obviously, if your problem is prohibitively large (say, hundreds of thousands of integer variables with no special structure), then solving the MILP directly is out of the question, and you'll have to content yourself with solving a relaxation, or finding a feasible point with large optimality gap. In your case, a problem with 26 variables is probably on the small side for MIQP.

In terms of providing integrality cuts to the solver, I don't know if you could do that, but in theory, if you knew how to provide good cuts, that would be valuable.

For an alternate approach, you could try MINLP solvers instead. The state-of-the-art code there is BARON, but there are others, like Couenne, and a few more. BARON generally does best on MINLPs, but isn't universally the fastest code for every problem. You could also take a look at something specialized for quadratic problems. GLOMIQO is really geared towards MIQCQPs, but could work for your problem. Both BARON and GLOMIQO are bundled with GAMS, so you could probably try submitting your problem to the NEOS server if there are no IP-type issues, and see if you get a solution more quickly.